# I am unable to select/enter data into a text area using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the html code of text area I am trying to automate :

```
<div class="large-5 end columns chckOutNote">
    <input id="LocationNotes_0__LocationNumber" 
     name="LocationNotes[0].LocationNumber" type="hidden" value="Location1"> 
    <input id="LocationNotes_0__ServiceProviderName" 
    name="LocationNotes[0].ServiceProviderName" type="hidden" value="trial"> 
    <input id="LocationNotes_0__WasPreviouslyFilled" 
     name="LocationNotes[0].WasPreviouslyFilled" type="hidden" 
     value="False">                    
    <label for="LocationNotes_0__Note"> trial</label>
    <br>
    <span id="LocationNotes_0__Note">500</span> characters 
    remaining
    <textarea class="counterpart" data-counter- 
     part="#LocationNotes_0__Note" data-max="500" data-val="true" data-val- 
     length="The field Note must be a string with a maximum length of 500." 
    data- val-length-max="500" data-val-required="The Note field is 
     required."id="LocationNotes_0__Note" name="LocationNotes[0].Note" 
     rows="10"> 
     </textarea>

    </div>
```

I tried to click on the element and then enter the data thru send keys but its throwing an error that it cannot find the focus of the element

Comment: use the xpath to find it

Comment: I tried with the xpath('//*[@id="LocationNotes_0__Note"]') but it is throwing me an error that it is not in focus. ('{WebDriverException}Message: unknown error: cannot focus element')
I even tried to select the element first and then tried it.. but still the same error

Comment: hm it might be in an iframe that you need to "focus" on first

Comment: Nope! :( Checked for Iframes too.. It is not in an Iframe..

Comment: Weird, is there crazy JS going on in the background or something?

Comment: Umm.. I am not sure.. I will try to see if I can find it .. Thanks

Comment: @spoorthy Suggestion: try ChroPath to find relative xpath. It may help

Comment: @ManojKengudelu Sure, Thank you

Comment: @spoorthy, show us what you have done so far. Also, you can try [Action chains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to move to element first and then click/send keys to the element.

Comment: It worked for me now. When I gave the Xpath with ('//*[@id="LocationNotes_0__Note"]')- It did not work but it worked when I went thru all elements from Root(Absolute Path). I am not sure what is wrong with the 1st one.

Comment: @spoorthy, It seems there are multiple elements with the xpath you have used earlier. Could you try using this xpath: //*[@id="LocationNotes_0__Note" and @class='counterpart']